# Visio: Can I have CommandButton on each page of visio with only one set of code doing same task on individual layer/s

Tags: visio

Is it possible to have a button (call) on each page that will use exactly the same code but only work to the layers on the page it is called from, thereby reducing the amount of code that is to be written / amended or added to.

Page-1 with CommandButton (or ToggleButton) code changes state of layer visibility.    it works.
Page-2  as Page-1 etc. if I write the code over and over it works.

I currently have 11 pages and each page has the same Layer Properties Names (There are 31 layers on a page)... (eg.Page-1 has ALLBACK, BAU, Callout.....) (Page-2 has ALLBACK, BAU, Callout.....) etc.  therefore 31*11 Commandbuttons = 341 buttons reducing thie code to 31 options would be good but I can't find the clues to do so.

for clarity each page is a timeline and each is for 6 months and Page-1 is 2018_Q34, Page-2 is 2019_Q12, Page-3 is 2019_Q34 etc....

Thanks for any help in advance.
Stephen

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it's been a very long time since I've done any VBA in Visio, so please, bear with me.

Open the VBA editor and select the Document Object. This assumes you're looking at the drawing you'd like to make these modifications to.

Create a new subroutine, name it whatever you'd like. This is what you're going to call when the button is pressed. Write the code you need to execute for the page.

Now, in the OnClicked() handler for the button call your new subroutine on the document.

I wish I still had a copy of Visio, I could just write you a simple example in about five minutes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: sorry to be so late, and thanks for the response. I have achieved my requirement. but it is very messy. now I am going to tidy up the whole code / process. In the end I have multiple buttons on each sheet of the visio and each button 1 or 2 etc on each sheet will call the same background module/code. The code will tun on/off/ relevant layers and print requirements in the Layers of the sheet. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather late answer, but maybe someone else can use it.

Instead of using these buttons I would recommend a adding a new menue to the Ribbon Bar. I use this tool to do so: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm

Then you can call sub with this button. At the beginning of the sub you can then use activepage to get the current page and work on it.

To make it even more flexible, change the sub to accept a page as parameter. Then create another module, in this module have multiple small subs. These Subs get called by your buttons and in return call your original sub(s) and pass the page you want to edit.

Comment: sorry to be so late, and thanks for the response. I have achieved my requirement. but it is very messy. now I am going to tidy up the whole code / process. In the end I have multiple buttons on each sheet of the visio and each button 1 or 2 etc on each sheet will call the same background module/code. The code will tun on/off/ relevant layers and print requirements in the Layers of the sheet. Anyway thanks again.